# How do you add a custom constraint in phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm looking to compare an interface by custom value in PHPUnit. Sadly, the built-in methods aren't enough and I want to extend them to add my own comparison.

I can tell from the [docs](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/extending-phpunit.html#write-custom-assertions) that there is a standard way to implement a new assertion. However, it also seems from a glance at the source code, that you can just write a custom comparator and [register](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/comparator/blob/master/src/Factory.php#L85) it somewhere to make use of it.

Where (and how) does one register a custom comparator?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually surprisingly easy.

You can see an example of a [comparator](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/comparator/blob/master/src/ScalarComparator.php#L16) in the source.

To add one of your own use the singleton instance of `SebastianBergmann\Comparator\Factory` to register the comparator in your PHPUnit `bootstrap.php` file.

```
use SebastianBergmann\Comparator\Factory;

$comparatorFactory = Factory::getInstance();
$comparatorFactory->register(new EquivalentComparator());
```

henceforth any call to `$this->assertEquals` in a test case will use the comparator.

The comparator checks if it's valid for the values, which makes it very flexible.